# Is it possible to load the parameters file while running?

Tags: ros, ros2, parameters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to load a parameter yaml file during runtime?

I have multiple parameter files that I would like to switch parameter file while running.

For example, I have

- setting1.yaml
- setting2.yaml

and at startup, setting1.yaml is loaded.
(This can be configured in launch.py)

After that, I want to load setting2.yaml and apply parameters while running.

The ros2 version is eloquent.

I am using jetson and jetson's OS(Jetpack) is based on ubuntu18.04 so I cannot use foxy.

In the foxy manual, I found the following section.

> **6 ros2 param load You can load**

> parameters from a file to a currently running node using the command:

> `ros2 param load <node_name> <parameter_file>`

https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Parameters/Understanding-ROS2-Parameters.html#ros2-param-load

However, there is no mention of this in the eloquent manual, and in fact the command resulted in an error.

https://docs.ros.org/en/eloquent/Tutorials/Parameters/Understanding-ROS2-Parameters.html

Any advice would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393889/is-it-possible-to-load-the-parameters-file-while-running?/) by [mutsuyuki](https://answers.ros.org/users/74222/mutsuyuki/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2022-01-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found this in the eloquent documentation:

https://docs.ros.org/en/eloquent/Tutorials/Parameters/Understanding-ROS2-Parameters.html#load-parameter-file

```
ros2 run <package_name> <executable_name> --ros-args --params-file <file_name>
```

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2022-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mutsuyuki](https://answers.ros.org/users/74222/mutsuyuki/) on 2022-01-08**:
Thank you for your answer.

What I want to know is how to reload the parameter file during runtime, but the method you suggested is seems to how to read the parameter file at the start.

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2022-01-08**:
In eloquent you need to stop node and reload as explained in the example.

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2022-01-08**:
If you need this functionality you could start PR, this feature was introduced for Galactic but recently added to foxy: https://github.com/ros2/ros2cli/pull/596

**Comment by [mutsuyuki](https://answers.ros.org/users/74222/mutsuyuki/) on 2022-01-08**:
Thank you osilva.
I understood that eloquent does not have the feature I'm looking for.

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2022-01-08**:
It’s also offered with Rolling. If this resolves your question please accept the answer. Thank you